# How can I get object's parameter of array with firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### I want to get `Q2` **array** and it **contains** `D1`'s **value**.

```js
{

'A': {
  'Q1': 'A1',
  'Q2': [
   {'D1': 'hello'}
  ]
 },

'B': {
  'Q1': 'A1',
  'Q2': [
   {'D1': 'hello'}
  ]
 }

}
```

> I tryed to query like this.

1. `where('Q2.D1','==','hello')`
2. `where('Q2.D1','array-contains','hello')`
3. `where('Q2','array-contains',{D1: 'hello'})`
4. ...

---

But they are not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not support querying map values inside arrays.  The only thing you can query for in an array is an **entire** array element.  So, you can search for the entire value `{'D1': 'hello'}`, but not just the map's field value 'hello'.

You will need to add a new structure for this, or change what you have.  For example, you could create a new array with all the possible values of D1, and use an array-contains query to find documents with the D1 you specify.